# How to "milk" a Rex?

Tags: technology, time-travel, survival, dinosaurs

Continue from https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/59315/how-to-defend-a-phone-booth-against-horde-of-zombified-carnivorous-dinosaurs. (This question concludes the time traveling phone booth storyline.)

After some times I made a shocking discovery that an **Albertosaurus's sperm** can prolong the phone booth invincibility even after the trial has ended, every hundred millilitres of the sperm used to coat the exterior finishes grant the booth up to 30 days worth of invulnerability. I know you are afraid of what's coming... how can I retrieve at least 1 year worth of the undiluted Albertosaurus's sperm solo?

Assuming I can only managed to raise USD$2000 from crowd funding to be spent at any legit hypermarket in the USA, killing is strictly prohibited. Albertosaurus belongs to the genus tyrannosaurid family which happens to be closely related to Tyrannosaurus Rex. Handwavium shall be applicable exclusively to the time traveling, invulnerability abilities and my own collection of the exotic sperm sample.

Difficulty: ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐

Comment: Your title says “rex”.  Your premise is absurd,so any answer will be POB.

Comment: @JDlugosz: Albertosaurus is actually related to T-rex and I hope to leverage on the experience and courage of collecting sperm sample from dangerous animal of today.

Comment: I clicked on this hoping to leave a one line answer explaining that, as reptiles, dinosaurs did not produce milk. Those were good times.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: I'm trying to obtain(milk) sperm from male mature Dino.

Comment: @user6760 Yes, yes you are.

Comment: ROFLMAO!  You get the +1 for taking the first step today.  I'm actually curious to see how this story turns out.

Comment: @Nolo: I feel you I'm actually quite surprised to gain a fan, but glad you like it unfortunately my sperm bank is almost depleted.

Comment: This question is incredibly amusing in so many very wrong ways I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

The same way anybody "milks" a large animal for sperm collection. First select an adult male Albertosaurus. Anaesthetize the beast, either grasp its penis and "persuade" it to ejaculate with either manual stimulation or vibratory ejaculation or electroejaculation devices. Of course, you will have to dodge marauding dinosaurs while doing so. You only have yourself to blame for setting up this dangerous wacky scenario.

Otherwise you kept collecting Albertosaurus sperm using the same method you collected your original sample until you have a year's worth. Really you only need one hundred millilitres worth at a time to extend your booth's invincibility by another thirty days. You only need several moths' worth to stay ahead of the game.

Surely there are brave and foolish individuals would rise to the challenge of "milking" Albertosaurs. Employ a few of them, or use this as an opportunity for them to join your time tourism business.

Comment: It might be complicated by the fact that reptiles normally keep their penis retracted inside the body.

Comment: @DrBob Nobody said it was going to be easy. :) Our knowledge of dinosaur genitalia & reproductive behaviour is a bit thin. I expect similarities to avian species. Another subject that needs more research. Adds to long list of topics.